# Get uptime output using “systeminfo | find "Boot Time"”

Tags: batch, uptime

How do I get system uptime using cmd:

```batch
 systeminfo | find "Boot Time"
```

A pause to let me read it, "press any key to continue..." then exit cmd when I press a key?

With `systeminfo | find "Boot Time"` alone, I get this and have to exit 'manually'.

```batch
C:\Windows\System32>Systeminfo | Find "Boot Time"
System Boot Time:        fre-15-juli- 2022, 23:08:52
```

Comment: [How do I get system boot time in batch? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54923023/how-do-i-get-system-boot-time-in-batch)

Comment: [How to get PC uptime in batch? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39883678/how-to-get-pc-uptime-in-batch)

Answer (score 0):

> *A `pause` to let me read it, "`press any key to continue...`" then exit cmd when I press a key?*
> *With systeminfo | find "Boot Time" alone, I get this and have to exit 'manually'.*
>
> ```powershell
> systeminfo | find "Boot Time" & pause & move nul 2>&0
> ```

---

```powershell
for /f tokens^=3*delims^=^:^   %i in ('"systeminfo | find "Boot Time""')do echo;%j & pause
```

---

- Using `pause`, it would be:

```powershell
for /f tokens^=3*delims^=^:^   %i in ('"systeminfo | find "Boot Time""')do echo;%j & pause
```

Since the intention is to get the output of your command:

```powershell
systeminfo | find "Boot Time"
```

---

Then just put your command in the `For /f` loop with tokens defined by a <kbd>`:`</kbd> and <kbd>`space`</kbd> as the output string delimiter

---

**Obs.:** Use two ***<kbd>`space`</kbd>*** in: `...delims^=^:^spacespace%i...`

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: Thanks Io-oI but didn't work for me. I wanted to use  e.g. systeminfo like so:

C:\Windows\System32>systeminfo | find "System Boot Time"
where I get back 
System Boot Time:          fre-15-juli- 2022, 23:08:53

C:\Windows\System32>
and here, get 'press any key to exit' whereupon cmd would exit on key press and the window would close.